# Как работает оператор (?)?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно чтобы при вводе в поле текста например сотрудник, алерт писал привет, директору здравствуйте итд. Не могу разобраться, следовательно решить задание. Я понял что это аналог if,но как им пользоваться нет понимания.

````
<body>

    <head>
        <script>
            let message = prompt('сотрудник');
            
            let login = (message == 'сотрудник') ? 'Привет': 
            (message == 'Директор')? 'здравствуйте!':
            (message == '')? 'нет логина':
            alert (login);      
        </script>;
    </head>;
</body>;```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще лучше такие конструкции никогда не писать. Именно потому, что в этой мешанине потом сложно разобраться

```js
let message = prompt('сотрудник');

let login = (message == 'сотрудник') ? 'Привет' :
            (message == 'Директор') ? 'здравствуйте!' :   'нет логина';
alert(login);
```

---

```js
let message = prompt('сотрудник');
let map = {
  'сотрудник': 'Привет', 
  'Директор': 'Здравствуйте'
};

alert(map[message] || 'нет логина');
```

Comment: Спасибо! Буду теперь сидеть разбирать это, а то на learnJS на эту тему,непонятно